# Can we use a UNC path for SQL Server 2012 ForEach File Loop?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a UNC path for a flat file. I'm trying to open this flat file and copy the info to our SQL Server 2012 database. The package works a treat from Visual Studio, but when it's run from the SQL Server Management Studio I get the following error:

> Foreach File Loop Container: Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

It's running under my user account in both instances.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually this ends up being a permission issue. Help me understand how you have the package running under sql agent. Could you post the job definition, take a look at sql server configuration manger and look at the account running Agent, etc.

Comment: Hi Marc At this point I have deployed my package to our 2012 SQL server. I have defined parameters in the project and have created Environments to support these parameters. I am executing this package from the SQL Management Studio Integration Services Catalogs (and choosing an Environment). The System::UserName is my network name and we have given the profiles/users _sqlint and _sqlde read/write access to the UNC....I will try it using SQLAgent next

Comment: My first question is to make sure this is a viable scenerio. We CAN use a UNC path can't we? After that it would mean this is a configuation/rights issue....

Comment: OK...it is just a configuration issue. When clicking and running the package from within SSMS, since I am not part of the admin group, my rights are restricted. If I run it as a proxy(?) there is no problem. Thx all....this question can be closed now

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the above warning message when trying to manually execute a package in SSMS via `Integration Services Catalogs > Project > Package > Execute...`

It turns out executing using this method will use the local SQL account (depending on how integration services are configured), which did not have access to UNC shares on the domain, despite the Everyone permission being applied to the share.

I created a SQL Server Agent job that simply executes the package, except this uses the domain agent account and now could read the files in the UNC share with no issues.